# Keeping Data annotations when Scaffolding

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, data-annotations, ef-core-6.0

I'm developing an ASP.NET Core Web App (Model-View-Controller), in .NET 6.

I'm using EF Core 6 and am practicing a Database First approach and every time I make a change in the database and do a Scaffold-DbContext I loose all Data Annotations that I've made in the entity classes.

Because of this I'm using View Models, which mostly are just straight copies of the entity classes, but with meta data.

I'm starting to feel that this however is not the correct approach? Is there another, better, way to to set the meta data for the properties, which remains when doing a Scaffold-DbContext?

Comment: The scaffolded DbContext is a partial class. You can move your `OnModelCreating` method to a separate file that won't be overwritten when the DbContext and entities are rebuilt

Comment: Way back when it was possible to use a *separate* class that contained only metadata annotations using the `MetadataType` attribute. This wasn't migrated to .NET Core at first but was [finally added in .NET 6](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39938). There's no documentation for how this works in .NET 6 though except the linked Github issue. You have to use `TypeDescriptor.AddProviderTransparent` explicitly to tell .NET where to find the annotations for the generated types.

Comment: Are you using EF 6 or EF *Core* 6? `MetadataType` worked in EF 6. It doesn't work in EF Core 6

Comment: Sorry, EF Core 6!
.NET 6 and EF Core 6. I'll edit the question to avoid confusion.